# Google has problems with sitemap?

Tags: typo3, sitemap, typo3-9.x

I set up a sitemap for pages with the built-in sitemap feature from TYPO3 v9. Now, Google search console says it can read the sitemap-**index** file successfully, but the sitemap itself can not be read: `Common HTTP error`.

The sitemap location, that should be read by Google  (`https://example.com/sitemap.xml?sitemap=pages&cHash=3a85856238f6a43714331de28ae671c08`), can be requested by browser directly.

Any hints on that?

Best, Lex

Comment: This is an error by Google, so Google should give more information than `Common HTTP error`. Maybe this can help: https://dynomapper.com/blog/22-sitemaps/70-common-sitemaps-errors-and-how-to-fix-them